# Large datasets and route analysis

Tags: mapping, gis, arcgis, network-analysis

I have an extremely large dataset that is growing fortnightly by around 7GB. The dataset contains a number of vehicles and their movements throughout the day. I need to convert the points into routes and currently am struggling to find any software packages that are able to handle 10+ million data points.

If anyone has any solutions of suggestions, I would greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of your data? CSV? shapefile?
Why do you mean exactly by 'building the routes', I have little knowledge of geoprocessing?

Comment: A first hint: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149657/gis-for-large-2gb-files

Comment: Hi,it is currently in CSV, but I can convert it what ever is necessary. I am able to plot the points as XY but I ideally need to convert them into routes so that I can carry out route/network analysis such as fastest/shortest route as well as journey/time analysis. Using ESRI Insights is out of the equation as it cannot deal with files over 100mb and ArcMap becomes incredibly slow when I have added all of the data.

Comment: As it is CSV, can you add a sample of your original data and a sample of your expected results? In other words, select few rows, perform the route analysis, export as CSV and add the initial sample and the output sample.